# laravel url is messed up

Tags: php, laravel

So, i basically have a view composer that fetches the user avatar and then passes it to the view. the user's avatar is http://placehold.it/150x150. However when laravel fetches it the url gets messed up instead it becomes ["http://placehold.it/150x150"]. is this a problem with blade? idk if this will be any help but here is the code:

```
     view()->composer('layouts.navbar',function($view)
      {
        $view->with('avatar', \App\User::getAvatar());
      });

    public static function getAvatar()
    {
 return User::Where('username', '=', Session::get('username'))->pluck('avatar');
    }
```

here is how the url looks like in chrome [image]

could this be a problem with laravel blade? because im doing img src={{$avatar}}

Comment: put your blade code ? you are returning the image as json?

Comment: offtopic: like the idea, just like http://devimg.com/

Comment: @ThomasMoors That looks cool will have a look at it

Answer (score 2):

`pluck()` returns an array. Try `value()` instead, or perhaps grabbing first index from the array

Comment: Depending on your version of laravel, it does.

Comment: is `first()` not a better replacement?